# iPhone Memory Management

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

There are a few concepts about iPhone memory management that have got me confused, so I was hoping that someone could clarify these.

(a) Say that I am calling a function which returns an image, and I want to store that returned image in a variable so that I can assign it to various other variables without having to re-call the image generation function each time. At the moment I am doing the following:

```
UIImage *storedImage = [someFunction returnImage];
```

and because the `storedImage` is not `alloc`'ed I am not releasing the variable.

However, should I be explicitly `alloc`'ing and releasing the `UIImage` instead?

```
UIImage *storedImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
storedImage = [someFunction returnImage];
...do stuff...
[storedImage release];
```

What is the implication of doing the direct assignment without `alloc` rather than `alloc`'ing the variable and then assigning?

(b) In the `init` method for various classes I am setting up the instance variables. At the moment I am doing the following:

```
self.arrayVariable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

However, I have seen others do the assignment this way:

```
theArrayVariable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.arrayVariable = theArrayVariable;
[theArrayVariable release];
```

or

```
theArrayVariable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
arrayVariable = theArrayVariable;
[theArrayVariable release];
```

...which is the same as above, but without the `self`.

What is the difference between the three methods and which is better to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding returning objects from methods, you should always return an *autoreleased* object from any method which does not begin with the name `alloc`, `new`, or contains `copy`. This is defined in Apple's [object ownership policy](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html), which states that you own any object that you create ("create" is defined as an object which you sent `retain` to, or used any of the aforementioned messages to retrieve an object), and that you are responsible for relinquishing ownership of that object by sending it the `release` or `autorelease` message.

The first method using `self` uses the *property setter* to set the instance variable to the argument (in this case whatever is on the RHS of the assignment).
This will do whatever you specified in your `@property` declaration (for example if you specified `retain`, the setter will `retain` the new value and `release` the old value).

The second method sets up a pointer to an `NSMutableArray` and passes it off to your property setter via `self`, which will most likely `retain` it, thereby bringing the reference count up to `2`, since the object was previously `alloc`-ed, so you need to `release` it after this line to bring it back down to `1`.

The third method will not work, because you are `releasing` an object with a reference count of `1` at the point of invoking `release`. How so you ask? Well, the first line sets up a pointer to an `alloc`-ed object, then *directly assigns it* to your instance variable, which will just point the ivar to the same object that `theArrayVariable` is pointing to. Then, that same object that `theArrayVariable` is pointing to gets sent the `release` method, which will effectively bring down the reference count of your ivar as well as the receiver, to `0`. At this point both your instance variable *and* `theArrayVariable` will get deallocated.

Comment: Thanks Jacob (and others) for your replies. Part (b) now makes perfect sense, and as Jumhyn said I assume that the first two methods are equivalent and just stylistic differences? Part (a) is still a bit confusing - is it valid to just use `UIImage *storedImage = [someFunction returnImage];` (this function does return an autoreleased object) or should I be `retaining` the object? If I am `retaining`, how do I release later (since I don't have a variable that I have explicitly `alloc`-ed which I can release?

Comment: Technically, the rule is "begins with `alloc` or `new`, or contains `copy`"

Comment: @Skoota, That case is a perfect use of `autorelease`.

Comment: Sorry Jacob, could you explain that a bit further? Are you saying that if I don't retain the object myself the "carpet could be pulled out from under me" at some point if the object is `autoreleased` when I still need to use it? Is this likely and therefore should I be retaining the object? If so, how do I then release it? Is `[storedImage release]` valid (even though I did not `alloc` the variable itself?).

Comment: @Skoota, Well, if you need that object to stick around, then send it the `retain` message. When you're done with it, you should send it `release` and it will be immediately deallocated.

Comment: @Jacob, At the moment I am not retaining the object but are referencing it in various locations within a method, without problem. At what point should I determine that it needs to be `retained`?

Comment: @Skoota If you need an object to stick around, immediately send it the `retain` message. When you know that you won't need it anymore, send it the `release` message. Simple as that.

Comment: @Jacob, So along the lines of the following? `UIImage *storedImage = [[someFunction returnImage] retain];` <followed by doing stuff> `[storedImage release];`

Answer (score 1):

a) The general rule for objective-c is that if you alloc it you must release it. In the first example, the method is returning a pointer to an object that already exists, and therefore you are not responsible for releasing it. In the second example, the first like is pointless since you aren't using allocated memory for stored image. This may cause a memory leak.

b) The first two are just stylistic differences, with no difference in outcome. In those, you will be left with arrayVariable pointing to the object returned by [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; (assuming you have retain in the @property declaration) and you should release it in the -dealloc method. As stated above, the third will not work because you are merely passing off the pointer.

Here is a useful article for understanding obj-c memory management: http://memo.tv/memory_management_with_objective_c_cocoa_iphone

Answer (score 1):

a) The code you gave does not do what you want. When you say

```
UIImage *storedImage = [someFunction returnImage];
```

someFunction returns an image object to you, but it does not guarantee that the image object will live forever. If you do not want the image to be freed without your permission in a future time, you should own it by calling retain like this:

```
UIImage *storedImage = [[someFunction returnImage] retain];
```

So now, this image object is owned by both someFunction and you. When you finish your work with this object you release it by calling release. When both someFunction and you call release for this object, it will be released (Of course if it is not owned by another owner).

In the other code segment, you create an image object and own it by calling

```
UIImage *storedImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
```

But then you lose its reference by assigning a new object to the storedImage pointer by calling someFunction. In this situation the image created by you is not freed but continues to live somewhere in the memory.